# I'm coding php for my project and then,

Tags: php, html

I coded the log-in page as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5> 
<html>
<head>

<? if (isset($_REQUEST['page1_submit'])) { 
if ($_REQUEST['pword'] == "meatball") { ?>
<center><h2>You entered the correct password on the first try!</h2></center>
<? } else { ?>
       <center><h2>Wrong Password! Try again.
       <form method="POST" action="password.php">
Password: <input type="password" NAME="pword" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="page2_submit" value="SUBMIT" />
<input type="reset" value="RESET" /><br />
       </form>
       </h2></center>
<? } ?>

<? } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['page2_submit'])) { 
if ($_REQUEST['pword'] == "meatball") { ?>
<center><h2>You entered the correct password!  But it took you two tries.</h2></center>
<? } else { ?>
<center><h2>Wrong Password Again! This was your second try.
<form method="POST" action="password.php">
Password: <input type = "password" name="pword" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="page3_submit" value="SUBMIT" />
<input type="reset" value="RESET" /><br />
</form>
</h2></center>
<? } ?>

<? } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['page3_submit'])) { 
if ($_REQUEST['pword'] == "meatball") { ?>
<center><h2>You entered the correct password!   But it took you three tries.</h2></center>
<? } else { ?>
<center><h2>Wrong Password Again! You're out of luck.</h2></center>
<? } ?>

<? } else { ?>

<!-- This is the first pass for the user – page 1 -->

<center><h2>Please enter your password to access this site!<br />
<form method="POST" action="password.php">
Password: <input type="password" name="pword"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="page1_submit" value="SUBMIT" />
<input type="reset" value="RESET" /><br />
</form>
</h2></center>

<? } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run this php, everything is appearing on the same page while password function is not properly working.

I even followed the guideline that our professor provided but can't find any clear solution to this..

Comment: *"our professor"* - why ask us for help if you have a professor? I gladly help people, but you literally pay someone already to help and teach you. I also dearly hope that this is just the basis of authentication your professor is teaching, as this is pretty terrible.

Comment: @Nytrix I tried to reach out but he is not very responsive to the question and literally just throws out tasks. And yeah, we are at the very beginning of the course, learning basics atm

Comment: You should read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php#84527)  note on the PHP manual website. It's in general a pretty great place for answers, it seems to be hidden though..

Comment: If you have learned sessions/cookies, I would just store the attempts in a session or cookie and use that value to create the messaging. You should not have 3 sets of near-identical html when you only have to change a few pieces of text based on the request.

Comment: @Rasclatt As of now, I have to follow the instructions that was given as like the code that I posted :( So I need to figure out what is wrong with that code..

Comment: no `<?php` in site

Comment: @nogad possibly short tagging enabled? Probably the issue though.

Comment: The script seems to work, I don't really understand what you are experiencing to be honest.

Comment: @Rasclatt Everything appears on one page while I need to make them appear separately

Comment: Like you need to break this script up into 3 pages instead of one?

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes that is correct. So for example, from the first page, when you get the password right, then the page should print out 'You entered the correct password on the first try!' without anything else, while if you get the password wrong, then it should prompt the user to retry

Answer (score -1):

In PHP some times `php.ini` is set to not allow short code.
`<?` is short for `<?PHP` if your server is not set to read `<?` then it will look the way it does. Try Adding `<?PHP` to all `<?` short codes.

If the server cant read the php starts and ends then it will just run them all together.

EX:

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<?PHP if (isset($_REQUEST['page1_submit'])) { 
if ($_REQUEST['pword'] == "meatball") { ?>
<center><h2>You entered the correct password on the first try!</h2></center>
<?PHP } else { ?>
       <center><h2>Wrong Password! Try again.
       <form method="POST" action="password.php">
Password: <input type="password" NAME="pword" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="page2_submit" value="SUBMIT" />
<input type="reset" value="RESET" /><br />
       </form>
       </h2></center>
<?PHP } ?>
```

Notice all the `<?PHP` code starts

**PLEASE DO NOT CODE LIKE THIS THIS IS TERRIBLE AND YOUR INSTRUCTOR NEEDS A LESSON ABOUT CLEAN CODE**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: I want you to make sure that it was not from me :(